How do I use the DynamoDB document client to set an attribute to a string representation of an integer?
I'm trying to use the AWS SDK for JS to set a DynamoDB item's attribute Password of type String to a string representation of an integer. This was my initial approach:
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import {
  UpdateCommand,
  DynamoDBDocumentClient,
} from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  region: 'us-east-2',
});
const dynamoDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoClient);

const key = { Email: lorem.ipsum@email.com };
dynamoInput.Key = key;

const attr = 'Password';
const attrVal = 456789;
dynamoInput.UpdateExpression = `SET ${attr} = ${attrVal}`;

dynamoDocClient.send(new UpdateCommand(dynamoInput));

But this yields the error ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "456789", near: "= 456789". I thought the issue might be that I was setting an attribute of type String to an integer, rather than a string representation of that integer. So I tried enclosing the integer 456789 in quotes of various kinds within the update expression. But apparently quote tokens are also syntactically illegal to directly include in update expressions. This led me to resort to the use of an expression attribute value as a placeholder for my string representation.
const attr = 'Password';
const attrVal = 456789;
dynamoInput.ExpressionAttributeValues = { ':v': `${attrVal}` };
dynamoInput.UpdateExpression = `SET ${attr} = :v`;

But this just gave me another error: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema.

DocumentClient is not doing anything special, it's simply setting the values as it's Inferred from JavaScript variables.
const attr = 'Password';
const attrVal = "456789";
dynamoInput.ExpressionAttributeValues = { ':v': attrVal };
dynamoInput.ExpressionAttributeNames={"#p":attr}
dynamoInput.UpdateExpression = "SET #p = :v";


I had already attempted to use expressions for both attribute names and values. Right now that's giving me the error ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions. I feel like it gave me a different error when I tried this before, but still, not sure how to get around this one.

Share your entire code that gives you an error with the inputs I shared. Share the code plus the specific error

I had not only omitted code but rewritten parts of it for the sake of simplicity. But here's a repo of the entire backend of my project. The function that produces the error is changeUserData (file), which is invoked by resetPassword (file), which is passed to an Express application as a PUT request handler (file).

I put the error in the README. In the process of reformatting it for readability.

I just noticed that the error seems to be coming from getPassword, implemented right above resetPassword in acct-controller.js (line 173). If that's right, the error must be coming from getUserData rather than changeUserData (line 51 of acct-model.js). My console.log() debugging statements threw me off.

You need to pass TableName as input parameter: https://github.com/brbavar/auth-backend/blob/15c98a80f8eb9c32c9bacd773f67416c9d00d70c/models/acct-model.js#L54

TableName is already passed as a parameter to dynamoInput on line 25, outside all the function definitions.
I still don't know what's going on. Though getPassword is in the stack trace, and resetPassword is not, the ExpressionAttributeNames exception is only thrown if both these functions are called. If I comment out the call to getPassword, and invoke only resetPassword, it once again throws ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema.

I have an idea now as to why I got the key element error. In the use case I'm testing now, no value has been assigned to reqPayload.Email. So until a value is assigned, I cannot use { Email: reqPayload.Email } as a key like I try to on lines 61–2. Now to figure out how that is linked to the ExpressionAttributeNames exception, or just stop using expression attribute names entirely.
Thanks for your help!
